# One principal cancelling a jointly granted power of attorney

Tags: india

This question pertains to Indian Law. However, the Law in this area is similar to British Law, so I would appreciate answers pertaining to British Law too.

Suppose a group of people (the principals) who jointly own land (say, the Trustees of a Trust which owns land) have jointly given power of attorney to someone to act for them (the agent).

I was told that if one of those persons chooses to cancel the power of
attorney, because of fraud or whatever reason (let's say it is fraud),
then the power of attorney needs to be remade/recreated by the remaining principals. Is this true? I have been unable to find any information about this online.

Comment: You are unlikely to get useful answers here: powers of attorney are a highly specialized and technical area of law. You should seek professional legal advice.

Comment: @DaleM Thanks for the comment. The source of the "I was told" was a lawyer. However, he hasn't provided any sources for his statement, though I have asked him for them. I thought maybe someone else might have a source. I realise it is a long shot, especially as most of the people on a site like this are not Indian, but I thought there was no harm in asking.